# Unable to Append HTML Elements to a Dynamically Created DIV with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamically-generated

Hi I am trying to `append()` some `HTML` elements to a Dynamically created `div` here is my page structure
`HTML:`

```
 <html>
      <head>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="main-wrapper">
           <div id="container">
              <div id="left-column">
                    <div id="filter-cont">Filtered</div>
              </div>
              <div id="right-column">
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </body>
     </html>
```

I am using an `AJAX` call to create `#container` and `#left-colum`, it is created and I have got the elements to append as well but the problem is that I can't select `#left-colum`. Here is the `JQuery` code that I have tried so far

`JQuery:`

```
<script>
//Ajax calling function
function display_data() {
     if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
          if (xhr.status == 200) {
              $("#main-wrapper #left-column").append(xhr.responseText);
              //$("#left-column").append(xhr.responseText); Not working as well
              if(html_string != ''){
                    $("#filter-cont").css("display", "block");
              }else{
                    $("#filter-cont").css("display", "none");
              }

          } else {
              alert('There was a problem with the request.');
          }
     }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what is the value of `xhr.responseText` ?

Comment: <div>Yes Filtered</div>

Comment: So the div main-wrapper is it created dynamically?

Comment: no the div container and its inner part is created dynamically

Comment: look for any error on console ;) html_string is not defined.

Comment: Can you show your more of your js as it stands I would expect this code to fail unless your `xhr` object is global and you have a var `html_string` which is not declared or set anywhere

Comment: Hi Can you please provide fiddle link for this ?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal is right, the problem is `html_string` is making a comparison that always return false.

Comment: No everything right. I can see the responseText in console and html_string is not empty.

Comment: If you are facing challenge in append `html` code in `div`, check out this fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/adminsunil/ep6n0u8w/

Comment: Create div container and its children dynamically and then append @SunilKumar

Comment: ok It means you want to create `<div>Yes Filtered</div>` this div only 1 time and the content of `this` div are dynamic ?
M i correct ?

Comment: No you have to create all the inner div container and the responsText from ajax <div>Yes Filtered</div> to append to div left-column